# When my future completes, how do I notify the observed variable?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

My template (item_view.html) references a variable (Map item) that's a getter to where it's actually defined in my ViewModel.

In item_view.html, things like:

```
<h1>{{item['subject']}}</h1>
```

In item_view.dart, item is:

```
  @observable Map get item => toObservable(viewModel.itemViewModel.item);
```

Note that it's referencing the observed `Map item` in the ItemViewModel below.

The MainViewModel itself has a getter to the ItemViewModel:

```
@observable ItemViewModel get itemViewModel {
    // Code to determine which item model to return.
    // ...
    return itemViewModels[id];
  }
```

And finally, the ItemViewModel itself gets the item, and should be populating `item` with the results.

```
class ItemViewModel extends Observable {
  final App app;
  @observable Map item = toObservable({});

  ItemViewModel(this.app) {
    getItem();
  }

  void getItem() {
    ...
    // TODO: This completes later, and item changes aren't being observed!
    f.child('/items/' + decodedItem).onValue.first.then((e) {
       item['subject'] = // ...and so on.
    ...
```

The problem seems to be that because the listener completes in the future, it's not updating the `@observable Map item` and not reflecting it in the template.

Am I missing a `toObservable()` somewhere? Do I need to use a `notifyChange()` (I'm not sure when to use that and can't find good examples)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't make much sense

```dart
@observable Map get item => toObservable(viewModel.itemViewModel.item);
```

Item is already observablebecause you made it observable with this line

```dart
@observable Map item = toObservable({});
```

When you assign another map to `item` you have to ensure that you make it observable before assigning it or make `item` final, then you get an exception when you try to reassign something else. You can then only add/remove items but you can be sure `item` stays an observable map.

```dart
@observable final Map item = toObservable({});
```

#### Update

```dart
@ComputedProperty('viewModel.itemViewModel.item')
@observable Map get item => toObservable(viewModel.itemViewModel.item);
```

http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/polymer/0.12.0/index.html#polymer/polymer.ComputedProperty#id_ComputedProperty-

Comment: Aha, makes sense. But then on something like `item = toObservable(e.snapshot.val());` I get `'item' cannot be used as a setter, it is final` which is the idea, but how do I handle something like that then (assigning the contents of map B to map A essentially)?

Comment: Either you don't make it final and try not to forget to call `toObservable(whateverMapYouAssign);` or you clear the map and add the new items `item.clear(); item.addAll(whateverMapYouAssign);` If you want to assign other maps several times expecially with a lot of items I wouldn't do it this way. Just ensure you use `toObservable()`. If you just create a map when the object is created and occassionally (for example initiated by user input) you add or remove a few items, make it final so you don't accidentally overwrite it with a non-observable map.

Comment: Ah, good to know `addAll` can handle that. At any rate, I guess my `toObservable()` was doing the trick, as you say, so short of updating the line that didn't make sense, this doesn't seem get me any closer to the solution.

Comment: I updated my answer (see last two lines). You should be able to use this instead the PathObserver and it should help solve the problem with building to JS but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Interesting! Seems much more sane. It almost works: I'm getting an occasional `The null object does not have a getter 'item'.` from my template. And also, I need to figure out where to now put the "Trick to respect line breaks".

Comment: Looks like `return itemViewModels[id];` doesn't yet have an itemViewModel for the `id`. Try to add a null check here and return a sane dummy value until this is proper initialized (it's hard to tell exactly because your question doesn't show all the related code).

Comment: Hrm. Code here: https://github.com/DaveNotik/dart-stack/blob/dev/lib/src/client/view_model/main.dart#L28

Comment: It was due to my own code. Got past it. @ComputedProperty works and compiles fine.

Comment: Would this work:

```
@ComputedProperty('viewModel.itemViewModel.item')
Map get item => readValue(#item);
```

?
basically `@observable` in a getter has no effect. `@ComputedProperty` actually lets you see the computed value, by calling toObservable on the getter, you will create a copy of the item every time, so it's going to be more expensive.

Comment: Yea, my code's like this now: `@ComputedProperty('viewModel.itemViewModel.item')
  Map get item {
    if (viewModel == null || viewModel.itemViewModel == null) return null;
    return viewModel.itemViewModel.item;
  }`

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind to the `itemViewModel` property, and notify changes to the `item` property when it changes.  Put this code in your element's constructor:

```dart
onPropertyChange(itemViewModel, #item, 
    () => _old = notifyPropertyChange(#item, _old, itemViewModel.item));
```

And add `var _old = null;` as a property (no need to make it `@observable` or anything) of your class.

To listen to a path, rather than a simple property:

```dart
new PathObserver(this, [#viewModel, #itemViewModel, #item])
      .open((newValue, oldValue) => notifyPropertyChange(#item, oldValue, newValue));
```

Here you're saying "when the value of the `item` property of the value of the `itemViewModel` property of the value of the `viewModel` property in `this` object changes, notify observes of my `item` property that the value changed from `oldValue` to `newValue`".  (Note that the `newValue` and `oldValue` are inverted in the callback and the call to `notifyPropertyChange`.)

Comment: Hmm. https://gist.github.com/DaveNotik/2a7aed3544691e18c65a leads to `The null object does not have a getter 'itemViewModel'.`.

Comment: You want to listen to changes to `viewModel` there, not `viewModel.itemViewModel`, since `viewModel` might be (and apparently is, at that point) `null`.  Might need a `PathObserver` if you're listening to changes inside the value.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: That's a great explanation. Fascinating. Alas, it doesn't seem to update. I must be doing something else wrong. Code: https://github.com/DaveNotik/dart-stack/blob/dev/lib/src/client/components/item_view/item_view.dart#L23

Comment: Are `MainViewModel` and `ItemViewModel` both observable?  Is the PathObserver firing? (try adding some code before `notifyPropertyChange`, say a `print()` or something, and check whether it's firing?)

Comment: It's not firing: https://github.com/DaveNotik/dart-stack/blob/dev/lib/src/client/components/item_view/item_view.dart#L25

Comment: I tried downloading and running your code, but ran into `pub get` issues, so I can't test it locally.  But I did notice you're mixing angular and polymer, which still don't quite get along.  You might be running into some issue regarding that.  Other than that, I dunno... sorry. :(

Comment: No, be sure to use the dev branch, master is dated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61010/discussion-between-david-notik-and-tonio).

Comment: Update: While this answerer helped me get the method in his updated answer working, I discovered it doesn't work well after compile. See http://goo.gl/egKk1G. Günter's approach w/ @ComputedProperty is more sane and simple and compiles fine.